# Android RxJava parallelization - computing with ExecutorService

Tags: android, concurrency, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have done successfully a small Java program with RxJava. The code is:

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int threadCt = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1;
        //multi-threading
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCt);
        Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(executor);

        final AtomicInteger batch = new AtomicInteger(0);

        Observable.range(1,80)
            .groupBy(i -> batch.getAndIncrement() % threadCt )
            .flatMap(g -> g.observeOn(scheduler)
                    .map(i -> intenseCalculation(i))
            ).subscribe(System.out::println);
    }



    public static int intenseCalculation(int i) {
       try {
          System.out.println("Calculating " + i +
                " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          Thread.sleep(500);
          return i;
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
    }
```

With this code everything works fine. Now I am trying to pass this code to Android:

```
        Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(executor);

        final AtomicInteger batch = new AtomicInteger(0);
        Observable.range(0, copiedCategories.size() - 1)
                .groupBy(i -> batch.getAndIncrement() % threadCt)
                .flatMap(g -> g.observeOn(scheduler))
                .map(i -> intenseCalculation(i))
                .subscribe(finishedListener::finished);
```

Inside the method finished() I am updating the GUI (finishedListener is a interface that the current Activity is implementing).

I am getting an error on the line with map(i -> intenseCalculation(i)):

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that void conforms to R
```

In build.gradle (for the app) I am using:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.9'
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java code you have:

```
.flatMap(g -> g.observeOn(scheduler)
               .map(i -> intenseCalculation(i))
        )
```

But in Android code you are performing `map()` on main stream:

```
.flatMap(g -> g.observeOn(scheduler))
.map(i -> intenseCalculation(i))
```

So, these are not the same thing, you have extra bracket in Android code, which entirely changes stream logics.

**Note**, you should be performing UI related operations on UI thread, so you have to perform `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` before subscribing to the stream, otherwise you'd end up in a crash.

Comment: You have copy-paste error. Your Java and Android code differ on operators sequence. In Java code you do `flatMap()` and inside this `flatMap()` you are doing `observeOn().map()`. But in Android code you are doing `flatMap()` and then `map()`. You have claimed that `Now I am trying to pass this code to Android`, but that is not the same code.

Comment: Indeed, my error. But still I get error. I have added also observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) after groupBy()

Comment: @OctavianIonel, "still I get error" is very wide term, can you point out what exactly?

Comment: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that void conforms to R